# Are pairwise ANOSIMs the correct post hoc test for an ANOSIM test?

Tags: r, biostatistics

I am comparing communities of insects between three different land use types (n=4 sites for each). I made an NMDS plot and all the groups looked very separate from each other (especially greenbelt sites). I figured an ANOSIM test would be an appropriate way to test if my communities are significantly dissimilar from each other (vegan). It came out significant with a large R. However, I want to know which groups are most different/significantly different from each other.

A few sources I found seem to mention pairwise-ANOSIMs as post hoc tests for it. While it makes sense, it feels like running three t-tests after an ANOVA rather than doing one Tukey test. Another source I found ran a PERMANOVA post-hoc test with adonis 2 instead of anything related to ANOSIM. Does anyone know if there is a specific test to do/ associated R code, or should I just do three more ANOSIMS, only comparing two land-use types at a time?